# How to ensure that the video resolution encoded by mediacodec is consistent with the camera preview angle？

Tags: android

I collected data through the camera, the camera rotated 90 degrees, and the preview size was 640*480.
Then through mediacodec encoding, the output resolution is 640 * 480, but the video width is high.

```
Camera.Parameters params = CameraInterface.getInstance().getParams();
params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
CameraInterface.getInstance().getCamera().setDisplayOrientation(90);

MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 640, 480);
```

I want the video encoded by mediacodec to be the same as the video recorded on the vertical screen.